# Summation over an Event given Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, summation, conditional-probability

Consider two events $G$, $A \in E(\Omega)$, where $E(\Omega)$ is an event space.

Consider **P(G|A)** is the **posterior probability** distribution **over $G$**. Now if you **sum over $G$**, then why is it equal to $1$?

In short, Why **$\sum_{G} P(G|A) = 1$**?

---

**Edit 1:**

I came across **Kolmogorov definition for Conditional Probability** and **Law of Total Probability**, according to which I can do following:

**$\sum_{G} P(G|A) = \sum_{G} \frac{P(G \cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{1}{P(A)} \sum_{G}P(G \cap A) = \frac{1}{P(A)}P(A) = 1$**

I am not sure if the calculation above is correct or not?

Even if it is correct, Why **$P(G \cap A) = P(A)$**?

Comment: $\Bbb P(G\mid A)$ is the posterior probability of $G$ over $A$.  If you sum such conditional probabilities over a *sequence* of events, $(G_k)$, which *partition* the outcome set $\Omega$, then $\sum_k \Bbb P(G_k\mid A)=1$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I did not understand about the partitioning of the outcome set $\Omega$! Also, what will be the role of $A$ in here!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_G \Bbb P(G\mid A)=1$ is true *when you have*: some sequence of *mutually disjoint* **events** $(G)$ whose *arbitrary union* is a superset of the event $A$.   That is that $(G)$ must form a partition of some superset of $A$ (and most usually this is the outcome set, $\Omega$).

$$\begin{align}\sum_G\Bbb P(G\mid A) &= \sum_G\dfrac{\Bbb P(A\cap G)}{\Bbb P(A)} && \text{conditional probability}\\ & =\dfrac{\Bbb P(\bigcup_G (A\cap G))}{\Bbb P(A)} && \text{probability for a union of }\textit{disjoint events}\\ &= \dfrac{\Bbb P(A\cap\bigcup_G (G))}{\Bbb P(A)}&&\text{distribution}\\& =\dfrac{\Bbb P(A)}{\Bbb P(A)}&&\text{since } A\subseteq \bigcup_G(G)\\ &= 1\end{align}$$